# Reading a custom file launched using Box

Tags: android, file, box-api

We have developed an Android app  which is used for rendering files of our custom file type (`.vds`). I am  able to launch my app for all the files (`.vds` file) which are stored on local storage, but if the files is stored on Box and I try to access them using the Box Android App then I am facing issues. I have created the following intent filter:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.vds" />
```

The problem is that in the corresponding activity I am able to get the intent, but if I try to read the URI (as our rendering logic is based upon file location) it gives me a path which doesn't exists on the SD card. What happens if we try to open a file using Box Android Native App? Where is the file downloaded and how should the downloaded file be accessed?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this one?  I've got the same exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve ur problem. Add the bellow intent filter.

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:pathPattern="*.snowdragon"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/snowdragon"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted above I've run into the same problem.  While I've not found what I would consider to be The Right Solution(TM) I do have a couple of things to add that might be useful to others:

First, I've discovered that if I download the file in Box (not the same as mark for offline) then clicking the item in either the download result dialog or in the subsequent notification that appears at the bottom of the app works.  Once you've dismissed that notification however, there does not seem to be a way to get back to the downloaded file from within Box.

Second, and let me qualify this by saying that I've not looked very closely at it yet but I think one could use the filename info in the intents for non-existent files to retrieve the file via the Box API, either directly from the cloud or possibly via API call to retrieve offline items.  I'm wondering if this is actually what Box is trying to get us to do with these bogus file paths, considering that they are so blatantly bogus:

```
12-04 10:09:29.318: INFO/ActivityManager(607): START u0
{act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///non_existent_dummy_folder/foo.abcdef typ=application/abcdef cmp=com.foo.bar/.app.FooViewer}
```